# NHibernate: Change query for authorization

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate, authorization

We are completely rewriting an existing product (and in the process changing from PHP to C#). One of the problems we encountered in our existing product is that of authorization: unless you make sure to check it always and everywhere, people get to see stuff they're not allowed to see. What's the best place to make sure it's always checked? I think the data layer is a great place to do this, but other suggestions are welcome.

We use NHibernate, so we've built a class that provides our entities. It looks like this:

```
class DataProvider {
    TEntity Get<TEntity>(int id) {
        return GetSession().Get<TEntity>(id);
    }

    IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>()
    {
        return GetSession().Query<TEntity>();
    }

    // ...
}
```

This allows me to call `DataProvider.Get<Person>(1)` or do LINQ queries using `from person in DataProvider.Query<Person>() select person`. Using Interceptors would allow me to deny access to any single object a user has no authorization for (though arguably I could insert that code in `DataProvider.Get`). It becomes troublesome when I try to use LINQ. Suppose I have a table with 1 million entities, but I only have access to 5 entities. Using Interceptors would retrieve the entire table and test each of the returned entities, but I only need 5 of them. The best thing I can imagine is injecting some custom SQL to tell NHibernate which objects to retrieve and ignore all others. We already have a system in place that can determine whether or not we have access to an object, let's assume we know how to make a query out of that as well.

What have I tried?

- Interceptors (too late, retrieves 1 million objects when only 5 are required).
- Events (IPostLoadEvent is the closest to what I need, but it's too late as well).
- A custom NhQueryable and DefaultQueryProvider. This throws an exception: "`The constant for 'MyQueryable<Person>' is not supported`", I think this is due to casting somewhere deep inside NHibernate. I doubt NHibernate was designed to allow a custom query provider or queryable.
- The OnPrepareStatement Interceptor. This is incredibly ugly. It allows me to edit the SQL, but all I get is a string. This would work, but I'm hoping there's a much more elegant way to do the same thing.

How do others handle their authorization code? How do you make sure nobody forgets to call the authorization checks?

Comment: Is this about authorization w.r.t to the data or the view ?

Comment: The data. Suppose I have 2 people in the database; Person A and Person B. A given user only has access to Person A, for that user I want to completely hide the existence of person B.

Comment: I would edit the question to reflect the topic more appropriately i.e. query encapsulation rather than authorization as it is misleading

Comment: I included the question about authorization because perhaps there's a better way to do this. Query encapsulation is the only (automated) method I could think of, but perhaps someone can come up with a method that doesn't require query encapsulation?

Comment: the intent of the question is to fetch data w.r.t particular criteria, i.e. query encapsulation / or any other nomenclature you wish to use and it has nothing to do with authorization as such, it would help yourself and others posters. cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at NHibernate filters.

Nice intro by Ayende here: http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters

We successfully used NH filters for a scenario, similar to yours, a few years ago. I've attached the essence of the filter below. In our case, all classes that we wanted to control access to inherited from a base class, "SecuredObject". We also had a notion of "Documents" in "Folders". It's kind of taken out of context here but perhaps it can give you some ideas.

`<filter name="GrantedSecuredObjectsOnly" condition="
...
Id IN 
(SELECT SecurityGrant.SecuredObjectId FROM SecurityGrant WHERE SecurityGrant.SecuredObjectConsumerId=:userId)) OR 
(Id IN (SELECT Document.Id FROM Document WHERE Document.FolderId IN (SELECT SecurityGrant.SecuredObjectId FROM SecurityGrant WHERE SecurityGrant.SecuredObjectConsumerId=:userId))
...
"/>`

userId is of course set to the currently logged on users ID.

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what we need. This still requires me to call a custom function every time I retrieve objects from the database. We're now testing a solution where each query is authenticated automatically (we've wrapped calls to Session.Query<>() and call 1 function to verify authorization). Then, for every object NHibernate instantiates we check authorization again. This method seems to work so far.

Comment: Actually, you won't need to call anything custom during querying. The filter can be enabled "under the hoods" when the NH session is created. The rest of the application doesn't really have to care about it. There is one catch though - when using the "Session.Get" and "Session.Load" methods of the NH API, the filters are not applied. Anyways... If you already have found a good solution for your case - that's great.

Answer (score 0):

Edited : what was i thinking !

I'm presuming you are stamping you Data with authenticationId / EnteredById

```
var userId = ...; //your authentication id

from entity in context.Entities    
where context.Entities.Where(x => x.EnteredById == userId && x.Id == entity.Id)
select entity;
```

i think this should do it

---

```
var query = new AuthorisedDataQuery<Entity>();
var entities = _dataProvider.Get(query);
```

writing the authorised data query implementation should pretty easy.

---

a query with a specification : pseudo code

```
var userId = ... //authentication
var specification = PredicateBuilder.True<Entity>();
specification = PredicateBuilder.And(specification, x => x.EntityId == userId); //default: build from this
var additionalCriterias = ...;
specification = additionalCriterias == null || additionalCriterias.Length == 0 
                  ? specification 
                  : GetComposedSpecification(additionalCriterias);

var query = from entity in context.Entities
            join anyOtherEntity in context.AnyOtherEntity on entity.EntityId equals anyOtherEntity.Entity.EntityId
            where db.Context.Entities.Where(specification).Contains(entity.EntityId)
            select entity;
```

**simply put what you are trying achieve is building of query criteria / specification from a default**

predicate builder via linkkit @ http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: That's pretty much what I want to achieve. Except instead of calling that code explicitly everywhere in my code, I want a single place where that code is injected. Ie: "from entity in DataProvider.Query<Person>() select entity" should only return entities I am allowed to see. The whole where-clause should be added in some generic way.

Comment: encapsulate the query, consequently you could then say _dataProvider.GetAuthorisedData<TEntity>(query) have a look at ayende's post http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton, you should get the basic idea

Comment: you could add further specifications as need be

Comment: I'm not sure how your link would help me here. Yes, it would create a filtered IQueryable (or IEnumerable), but if I join that with anything won't it simply ignore those checks for the joined entities? Perhaps I'm solving this at the wrong level? I'll give this a shot to see if I can break it.

Comment: if you are stamping the authenticationId / EnteredById on each record, why would this effect the query ? all you would be doing is adding additional specification w.r.t entity i.e. a specification could be {entityId, OrderDate, ... }